# Postgres query - calculating busiest 1 hour period

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that records flights from an airfield, it has one row per flight and includes a timestamp field takeOffTime.

I want to find the busiest rolling 1 hour window. My first attempt looked like this….

```
select count(*), date_trunc('hour', takeOffTime) 
from flight 
group by date_trunc('hour', takeOffTime)
order by 2
```

However, there’s a big problem here. I can use the above to discover the busiest calender hour i.e. the busiest hour measured from one hour marker to the next.

What I really want is to find the busiest 1 hour rolling window. Example, for one of my datasets I know that the busiest calendar hour is from 11am to 12am, however I also know (using a pencil and paper) that on the same day the busiest rolling 1 hour window was from 11:13:48 to 12:13:48. How do I write a SQL query to give me this answer?

Thanks

data and example....

```
DROP TABLE flight;

CREATE TABLE flight (takeoffTime timestamp);

INSERT INTO flight VALUES
('2018-04-28 12:05'), 
('2018-04-28 13:05'), 
('2018-04-28 14:01'), 
('2018-04-28 15:05'), 
('2018-04-28 16:05');
```

Run my original query...

```
select count(*), date_trunc('hour', takeOffTime) 
from flight 
group by date_trunc('hour', takeOffTime)
order by 2;
```

And it will tell you that there is one flight per hour. However, look carefully at the actual data and you can see that the busiest 1 hour period is actually between 13:05 and 14:05 when there are two flights - as revealed by Gordons answer.

Comment: Update the question with sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use a self-join and aggregation:

```
select f.takeOffTime, count(*) as cnt
from flight f join
     flight f2
     on f2.takeOffTime >= f.takeOffTime and
        f2.takeOffTime < f.takeOffTime + interval '1 hour'
group by f.takeOffTime
order by 2 desc
limit 1;
```

This is not terribly efficient.